# How to remove the last item of the nav bar while wrapping?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, nav

With the help of media screen i'm able to remove the last item when the max-width reaches 820px, but I need to remove it when the last letter of the word touches the end screen. With respect to every word getting removed when the screen size is reduced.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Store</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="head2">
      <span>Products: </span>
      <nav class="navigation">
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="">Mobiles</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="">Fridge</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="">TV</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="">Washing Machine</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="">Watch</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="">AC</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="">Head Phones</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="">Speakers</a></div>
      </nav>
      <div class="arrow">></div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Do I have to set screen max width for every element like 740px for "Head Phones" and so on?

```
<style>
.arrow{
  color: white;
  display: none;
}
.head2{
  background: #20293f;
  display: flex;
}
.navigation{
  display: flex;
}
span,.navigation>.nav-item>a{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
.navigation>.nav-item{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 820px){
  .navigation>.nav-item:last-child{
    display: none;
  }
  .arrow{
    display: block;
  }
}
</style>

</html>
```

Comment: yes, of course. But why would you do such a thing? Why not use some sort of mobile menu?

Comment: I am using a mobile menu but at some point of width

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 680px){
  .navigation>.nav-item:last-child{
    display: none;
  }
  .arrow{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .arrow{
  color: white;
  display: none;
}
.head2{
  background: #20293f;
  display: flex;
}
.navigation{
  display: flex;
}
span,.navigation>.nav-item>a{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
.navigation>.nav-item{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 680px){
  .navigation>.nav-item:last-child{
    display: none;
  }
  .arrow{
    display: block;
  }
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <html>
<head>
  <title>Store</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="head2">
      <span>Products: </span>
      <nav class="navigation">
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="">Mobiles</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="">Fridge</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="">TV</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="">Washing Machine</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="">Watch</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="">AC</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="">Head Phones</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a href="">Speakers</a></div>
      </nav>
      <div class="arrow">^</div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.